# Gunicorn not serving png

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm developing a Django app that displays data in various forms including tables and bar charts. It uses matplotlib to create the bar chart as a png. It then returns it using this code:

```
.
.
.
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
return response
```

Everything works fine when I use the built in Django development server. However, when I use:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

everything works except the bar charts. Instead of a bar chart I see the URL. Do I have to run nginx to get gunicorn to display png images or is there something else I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Output from curl:

```
 About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /myapps/bar_chart1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn/0.12.1
< Date: Mon, 16 May 2011 14:05:00 GMT
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: image/png
< 
* Leftovers after chunking.  Rewinding 16379 bytes
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: When you run it with Gunicorn, what happens when you use curl to download a PNG? If you could paste the output of something like: `curl -v http://host.name/path/to/png > my.png`, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! This is related to a bug we fixed in Gunicorn recently [1]. Apparently Django won't set a Content-Length when using HttpResponse.write(). You can either set this by hand or apparently just adding django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware to your middleware list will cause Django to add the Content-Length.

We'll be releasing a new version of Gunicorn in the next couple days so the original bug will be fixed shortly.

[1] https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/commit/d83c63429eba755f5971217917e57feee85034be

Comment: Benoît has just pushed the 0.12.2 release to PyPI which includes the commit listed above. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gunicorn/0.12.2